# Performance issue in 12c - Additional Full table scan after index range scan

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-12c, scan

I am trying to improve the performance of a procedure which we recently moved from 11g to 12c. I am simply using a refcursor which gets the result set from an underlying query. In 12c I am having a significant performance hit. The query running time in 11g was less than 3 seconds while in 12c it is taking more than 2 minutes.

In 12c, the stats are not gathered for the last 1 month(testing environment).

When I compared the execution plan, the only difference I could see was that there is a full table scan following an index range scan happening for a table.
This full table scan is not present in 11g.

Following is the plan snippet where this is happening. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
18 STATISTICS COLLECTOR                                  
  17 VIEW       VIEW SYS.VW_1 Cost: 137  Bytes: 81  Cardinality: 9                              
    16 HASH UNIQUE  Cost: 137  Bytes: 432  Cardinality: 9                          
     15 FILTER                      
      14 CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING (UNIQUE)                  
       6 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TAB1 Cost: 2  Bytes: 27  Cardinality: 1              
        5 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TAB1_PK Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1          
       13 HASH JOIN  Cost: 5  Bytes: 312  Cardinality: 8              
        11 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 5  Bytes: 312  Cardinality: 8          
      8 STATISTICS COLLECTOR      
     7 CONNECT BY PUMP  
       10 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED TABLE TAB1 Cost: 3  Bytes: 216  Cardinality: 8      
     9 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TAB1_IE2 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 8  
      12 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE TAB1 Cost: 3  Bytes: 216  Cardinality: 8
```

Comment: ok, so it looks like you may be doing BULK LOAD operations (CTAS or INSERT INTO ... SELECT or simlar) so in 12c Oracle will collect stats. You can provide hint NO_GATHER_OPTIMIZER_STATISTICS to turn that part off (add it to SELECT part of the query).

Comment: My code doesnt have any bulkload operations. Just passing the resultset to a refcursor to load in the application. 
Is there a difference in compiler in 12c which interprets the plan differently? Should we change the entire code in some other way?

Comment: Better answered if we see the query and the query for refcursor.